# How to call a function, when page is scrolled to certain element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, scroll

can you tell me why my code doesn't work. I want to call a function when page is scrolled to certain element. (I would like to find solution in vanilla js without using jQuery)

```
const numberContainer = document.querySelector('.numbers');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    const elementPosition = numberContainer.scrollY;
    
    if(scrolled == elementPosition){
        counter();
    }
})
```

Comment: Check the IntersectionObserver API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: You will find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/55181673#55181673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use offsetTop for numberContainer

```
const elementPosition = numberContainer.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called `scrollY` on an **[HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)** (`numberContainer` in your case).
`offsetTop` is the property you're looking for.

More on it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

Answer (score 0):

This code can solve this problem in javascript

```js
 // Get the div element with the ID "monkey".
 const monkey = document.getElementById('monkey');


  checkVisibility = () => {

 // Check if the div element is scrolled into view.
 if (monkey.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight/2 ) {

   // Change the background color to red.
   monkey.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   
   monkey.innerText = "I made it at last hurrayyyyy!!! " + window.innerHeight
   
   
   //If you want this to happen only once then you can add line 20, if not don't remove the eventlistiner as I did in line 20(I mean delete line 20)
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkVisibility )
   
 }
}


// Set a listener for the "scroll" event below the function.
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkVisibility );
```

```css
           EXPLANATION TO CODE

/*
COMMENTS
see JAVASCRIPT line 11: I did 
window.innerHeight/2  ...divided by two will mean that when the monkey div gets to half of the screen, the function is fired. you can mathematically twerk that to what you want. 

if you remove the divide by two entirely, by that I mean to change the code at line 11 as 
if (monkey.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight) {

immediately the monkey div appears on the screen the function is fired.

CAUTION: DO NOT PLACE LINE 27 ABOVE LINE 8 AS YOU WILL BE SETTING THE EVENT LISTENER AHEAD OF THE FUNCTION AND IT MAY NOT WORK. AT LEAST WHEN I TRIED IT OUT, THAT WAS WHAT I FOUND.

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ZigLewis solution to making a function run when an element gets to a particular screen position
    </title>
</head>

<body>




 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repelr vel duptates mollitia rem doloremque excepturi reprehenderit fugit exercitationem incidunt. Non deleniti beatae fuga fugit culpa aliquam fugiat error .</p>
 
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repe </p>
<p> SCROLL UP SLOWLY TILL YOU CANT SEE ME! </P>
<br>
<hr>
 

<div id = "monkey"> KEEP YOUR EYES HERE ON THE MONKEY </div>
<hr>
<br>
<br>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repelr vel duptates mollitia rem doloremque excepturi reprehenderit fugit exercitationem incidunt. Non deleniti beatae fuga fugit culpa aliquam fugiat error provident facere quo soluta porro accusamus qui sed assumenda, alias excepturi ratione minus voluptates vel aspernatur cum doloribus sapiente. Libero, consequatur quam at quos quae rem.
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repelr vel duptates mollitia rem doloremque excepturi reprehenderit fugit exercitationem incidunt. Non deleniti beatae fuga fugit </p>
 


 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repelr vel duptates mollitia rem doloremque excepturi reprehenderit fugit exercitationem incidunt. Non deleniti beatae fuga fugit </p>
 
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem doloremque molestiae delectus asperiores, eaque totam? Dicta deleniti repelr vel duptates mollitia rem doloremque excepturi reprehenderit fugit exercitationem incidunt. Non deleniti beatae fuga fugit </p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you go full page you won't see this solution play out, because the content is too small and cant be scrolled. If there is no scrolling the solution won't work. That was the essence I added many DUMMY words. Hope this helps someone.